# Python, Efficient implementation of multi-thread IO

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess

Currently, I have some parallel implementation of intensive I/O task. 
for example

```
   def func(i):
      # Write to i.txt
      subprocess.Popen(str(i).txt).wait()   

      # Another external process to analysis i.txt and generate image i.png
      subprocess.Poen(str(i).txt).wait()    

      # read i.png
      color = open("i.png")
      return color

   pool = ThreadPool(4)
   for i in range(1000):  # Could be thousands of files
      pool.apply_async(func,i)
```

The two external processes are either CPU computation intense or GPU intense.

Compare with single thread, it has significant speed up. 
But i still wonder if there are another optimization? can be used.

Can the sequence of IO be optimized?

for example, instead perform three I/O in one function,  split I/O use three thread queues to avoid the wait() or file reading.

I'm new to python, any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Are the two programs able to output to stdout / stdin? If so, you can always pipe the output from the first subprocess to the second, then read from the stdout of the second (To avoid filesystem I/O).

Also, why not just `pool.map(func, range(1000))`?

Comment: At first you would have to fix your function, which is far from working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am assuming that your processes are linked and thereby cannot be run asynchronously.

I would suggest piping the processes instead of using wait. Something like below

```
def func(i):
    args_write = ['write', '%s.txt' % str(i)]
    args_read = ['read', '%s.txt' % str(i)]
    args_img = ['color', '%s.png' % str(i)]
    # Write to i.txt
    process_write = subprocess.Popen(args_write, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
    # Another external process to analysis i.txt and generate image i.png
    process_read = subprocess.Popen(args_read, stdin=process_write.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
    # read i.png
    process_img = subprocess.Popen(args_img, stdin=process_read.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)

    process_write.stdout.close()
    process_read.stdout.close()
    color = process_img.communicate()[0]
    return color

pool = ThreadPool(4)
for i in range(1000):  # Could be thousands of files
    pool.apply_async(func, i)
```

Rest looks good.

Comment: So use the pipe would not block the thread?  Because the subprocesses are writing to HDD directly, I use .wait() to make sure the file creation is completed, are so the next subprocess would be able to read the created file.

Comment: the pipe would not block the thread and it is possible that '.wait() ' would.

[subprocess - wait docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait)